# jquery function not working in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari

I have the following functions not working in Safari for PC or MAC:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j(".wpp_search_button.submit:eq(0)").click(function(){
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'Header Search', '', 1]);    
    });
});

$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j(".wpp_search_button.submit:eq(1)").click(function(){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'Body Search', '', 1]);
    });
});
```

It is supposed to track onclick for searches in my site, but it doen't. Any suggestion?

Comment: "But it doesn't" does not constitute enough detail to make this question answerable.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try and bind to mousedown to see if that fixes the issue:

```
$j(".wpp_search_button.submit:eq(0)").mousedown(function(){
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'Header Search', '', 1]);    
});

$j(".wpp_search_button.submit:eq(0)").mousedown(function(){
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'Header Search', '', 1]);    
});
```